# Errors with missing return statement

Tags: java

Every time i try to compile my code i get a error about a missing return statement. Any ideas about whats wrong with my code?

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
So i fixed a couple of things, but now im getting an error where my variable 'result' might not have been initialized, any suggestions?

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import java.io.*;
    public class facts
    {
      public static void main(String[]args)
    {

    String input;
    int x;
    char y,prime,perfect;
            do{
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an integer");
        x = Integer.parseInt(input);
        if(x%2==0)
                System.out.println("The integer is even - it is evenly divisible by 2");
            else
                System.out.println("The integer is not even - it is not evenly divisible by 2");
            prime = isPrime(x);     
            if(prime == 't')
                System.out.println("The integer is a prime number");
            else
                System.out.println("The integer is not a prime number");
            perfect = isPerfect(x);
            if(perfect == 't')
                System.out.println("The integer is a perfect number");
            else
                System.out.println("The integer is not a perfect number");

        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Y for another number, anything else to quit");
        y = input.charAt(0);
        }while(y=='Y');
            System.out.println("Good Bye");

            System.exit(0);
}            
    public static char isPrime(int x)
    {
        for(int y=2;y<x;y++)
        {
            if(x%y==0)
                return 't';
            else 
                return 'f';
        }
    }
    public static char isPerfect(int x)


 public static int triAng(int x)
{
    int result,z,y = 1;
    while(y<=x)
    {
        z=y*(y+1)/2;
        y++;
        System.out.println(z);
        result = z;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: First thing to do: fix your indentation. Second thing to do: add braces around all your `if` statement bodies (or sooner or later it *will*) bite you. Fourth thing to do: change a method which returns a true or a false value from returning `char` to returning `boolean`. Then consider what you want to do if `x % y` is never 0.

Comment: I'd say you're missing at least 2.

Comment: @JonSkeet What would the mystic third point be? :)

Comment: @skuntsel I've been wondering if this is perhaps one of the legendary Jon Skeet facts: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts but I can't find anything.

Comment: @skuntsel: Why, to come up with a third thing to do, of course ;) Oops. (I'm sure I *did* have another one. Possibly it was to write shorter methods, and then I saw that they weren't *that* long after all.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Probably the third one was so frightened that it decided to vaporize from the comment (do not do `*`-type imports ?). By the way, it's strange the code hasn't been prettified on its own ;)

Comment: @user2340601 see my edited answer for your new problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put return statements after your `for` loops and return a default char or null, in case the loops would not be entered. And in your `isPerfect`, even the if may not be entered.

For your `variable 'result' might not have been initialized` problem, the problem is that line:

```
int result,z,y = 1;
```

only the `y` variable is initialized to 1. As you might not enter the while loop, then the return statement would return `result` with it not having been initialized, so you need to explicitly specify a value to it (null or whatever integer).
If you want them all to be 1 you can do:

```
int result,z,y;
result = z = y = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `isPerfect` method, you don't have a return statement for the case that the code does not enter if `if(x%y==0)` block.

Answer (score 0):

For example, this code might not return if x <= 1 or if x%y is never 0:

```
 public static char isPerfect(int x)
    {
        int y,z=0;
        for(y=1;y<x;y++)
        {
            if(x%y==0)
            {
                z+=y;
                if(z==x)
                    return 't';
                else
                    return 'f';
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `isPrime` and `isPerfect` methods, your code may not enter in the for loop. To adjust it, put a default return on the end of these methods or throw an exception.